InitialContext Lookup under Java 11 is empty (Unit-Tests)
We write our Unit-Tests with OpenEJB (7.0.9) under Java 8.
Now we switch to Java 11 but the Lookup to our Beans are not working.
We always get a NameNotFoundException when we use Context.lookup(String name).
The OpenEJB-Logs shows the JNDI so we don't think that's the problem. We tried also with Version 8.0.16 and 9.0.0 with the same result. With Java 8 and Version 8.0.16 it works.
Here is the log with OpenEJB 8.0.16 under Java 11 (i replaced module-name with XXX):
INFORMATION: Beginning load: XXX\target\test-classes
INFORMATION: Configuring enterprise application: XXX\classpath.ear
INFORMATION: Auto-deploying ejb ProcessDefinitionService: EjbDeployment(deployment-id=ProcessDefinitionService)
INFORMATION: Created Ejb(deployment-id=ProcessDefinitionService, ejb-name=ProcessDefinitionService, container=Default Stateless Container)

We use a Lookup-Class for the lookup where we try with several lookup-paths (java:global/classpath.ear/XXX/ or global/classpath.ear/XXX/):
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
try {
    return (T) ctx.lookup(name);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return (T) ctx.lookup(beanName(name) + "!" + clazz.getName());
}

That´s out Properties:
System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory"); System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath.filter.descriptors", "true"); System.setProperty("openejb.deployments.classpath.include", ".*XXX.*"); System.setProperty("openejb.jndiname.format", "{deploymentId}");
The production-Lookup is working (under WildFly) with the same Lookup-Class.
When i debug the tests, the methods "ctx.getNameInNamespace" and "ctx.getEnvironment()" are always empty.
Any ideas?
